# Laravel with Sximo CRUD Builder: Synching table modifications with forms

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel with Sximo CRUD Builder and my question is this:
In case I need to modify my data model after I generated a module, how do I sync the table changes with the Sximo form definitions (which are encoded in the db in tb_module, module_config)? I tried the rebuild function but that only regenerates index, form, and grid view files.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know you surely did find a solution for this.
But for reference go to "SQL" tab and click on "Save SQL".
The "Table Grid" will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content2 = tf_read2('your encoded code');

$contents2 = "<textarea rows=\"6\" cols=\"25\">".$content2."</textarea>";
echo $contents2;
```

Comment: Please do not just post code, tell us what we're looking at.